# Exclude date column from groupby dataframe with sum function on it

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge, group-by

I have a df, and I gropedby it into another dataframe, with sum function, it excluded some columns, but **date** is vital for further calculation

```
grdf = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month', 'Percentage']).sum()
grdf['Gross Sales'] = grdf['Gross Sales'].astype(float)
grdf['Sum'] = grdf['Gross Sales'].cumsum()
```

What a best way for append, merge, reindex, mask, meld, concat, intersect,
 you_name_it - my datetime column?

```
 -                         Net Units  Net Sales  Gross Sales     Sum  Payout
    Year Month Percentage                                                   
    2017 11    70%                 3     147.97       103.58  103.58  103.58
         12    70%                 1      24.99        17.49  121.07   17.49
    2018 1     70%                 2      49.98        34.99  156.06   34.99
         2     70%                 3      74.97        52.48  208.54  104.96
         3     70%                 1      24.99        17.49  226.03   17.49
         4     70%                 1      24.99        17.49  243.52   17.49
         8     88%                 2      89.98        79.18  322.71  114.17
         9     88%                 1      64.99        57.19  379.90   57.19
         10    88%                 3     104.97        92.37  472.27  149.56
         11    88%                 2      79.98        70.38  542.65   70.38
    2019 1     88%                 2      39.98        35.18  577.83  105.56
```

> ++++

```
          Day                     Product Base Price  Net Units  Net Sales  Gross Sales Percentage  Year  Month   Payout     Pay Day
0  2017-11-11         asdasdasdnts     $69.99          1      69.99      48.9930        70%  2017     11        x           x
1  2017-11-13         asdasdasdnts     $69.99          1      69.99      48.9930        70%  2017     11        x           x
2  2017-11-27         asdasdasdnts      $7.99          1       7.99       5.5930        70%  2017     11  103.579  2018-01-11
3  2017-12-06         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2017     12        x           x
4  2018-01-03         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      1        x           x
5  2018-01-17         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      1        x           x
6  2018-02-10         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      2        x           x
7  2018-02-19         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      2        x           x
8  2018-02-28         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      2  104.958  2018-04-14
9  2018-03-04         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      3        x           x
10 2018-04-22         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      17.4930        70%  2018      4        x           x
11 2018-08-01         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      21.9912        88%  2018      8        x           x
12 2018-08-22         asdasdasdial     $64.99          1      64.99      57.1912        88%  2018      8  176.789  2018-10-06
13 2018-09-19         asdasdasdial     $64.99          1      64.99      57.1912        88%  2018      9        x           x
14 2018-10-15         asdasdasdial     $64.99          1      64.99      57.1912        88%  2018     10  114.382  2018-11-29
15 2018-10-23         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      21.9912        88%  2018     10        x           x
16 2018-10-26         asdasdasdock     $14.99          1      14.99      13.1912        88%  2018     10        x           x
17 2018-11-20         asdasdasdial     $64.99          1      64.99      57.1912        88%  2018     11        x           x
18 2018-11-20         asdasdasdock     $14.99          1      14.99      13.1912        88%  2018     11  105.565  2019-01-04
19 2019-01-04         asdasdasdnts     $24.99          1      24.99      21.9912        88%  2019      1        x           x
20 2019-01-04         asdasdasdock     $14.99          1      14.99      13.1912        88%  2019      1        x           x
```

> I group by month, so my data was summed, amount of rows - is not the same

Comment: What does the original dataframe look like?

Comment: Could you please add an example of your original dataframe?

Comment: @Ghorich - Updated!

Comment: @Mr_Z - Updated!

Comment: @Oleg - Can you check if help transform method from dupe? If not, I can reopen question.

Comment: @jezrael - unfortunately not, I group by month(so my data was summed), amount of rows - is not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

```
In : df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],
                        [4, 5, 6],
                        [1, 5, 7]],
                        columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])                   

In : df
Out: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  1  5  7

In : df.groupby('A').agg({'B':np.sum, 'C':'first'})
Out: 
   B  C
A      
1  7  3
4  5  6
```

Hence you can decide which operation to use on each column. You just have to say what you want for the 'date' column (first might be ok).

Comment: with `'last'` - works **PERFECTLY**! just like I want, thank you man ^___^